# How to inject a mocked service into a dynamically created class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

So I have a `@Spy` which performs a new object creation, related to the refactoring pattern of -> (Method to Object) however, that newly created instance does not have its dependent services injected in.

The code is obviously not my property to post up on this forum, but in pseudo logic, Ill try to get the message across below:

```
@Mock private SpecialistService specialistServiceMock;
@InjectMocks private TestObject testObj = new TestObject();
```

although `TestObject` inherits this service from its Abstract parent class, and any usage directly in `testObj` the `specialistServiceMock` is not null and works fine.

Now, when `testObj` hits the new `RefactoredMethodToObject()` class, and calls its `invoke()` method, it needs to have `specialistServiceMock` to do a few things, but `specialistServiceMock` is null.

I appreciate this looks to be beyond Mockito's capability, I do have PowerMock at hand too.

So in a nutshell, I need to have the `specialistServiceMock` mocked for actions needed to be performed in the dynamically created instance of `RefactoredMethodToObject()`.

Any ideas would be welcome, and if you need more information, let me know. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. You have an @autowired SpecialistService inside your TestObject, right? And now you extracted the method which deals with this service into a new object? How do you instanciate the newly created object?

Comment: The class is instantiated via a builder class in the implementation, I have no logic in the tests to either mock or stub that behaviour as yet.

Comment: You could make your builder injectable and inject a builder object with service mock injected.